# Ignoring a backreference in a rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm probably not wording my title correct, but here's my rule:

`RewriteRule ^our-thinking/(.*)/(.*)$ /$2 [L,NC]`

So I want `http://hostname/our-thinking/scenarios/this-is-a-post` to load `http://hostname/this-is-a-post`.

But with my current rule, it always becomes `/scenarios`. Even if I change $2 to anything else, it's always `/scenarios`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this rule is being invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to capture something that you don't want to use on RHS.

Try this rule with better regex:

```
RewriteRule ^our-thinking/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

If you want an **external redirect** (i.e. to change URL in browser), use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^our-thinking/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thanks, anubhava. Totally new to this, did not realize about parenthesis.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want URL to change in browser then add `R` flag also as: `RewriteRule ^our-thinking/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R]`